# Disable auto creation of birthday events for contacts in Outlook 2010

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, google-calendar, google-sync

Does anyone know how to disable the creation of birthday events in Outlook 2010?

I have two computers and one mobile which all sync through a Google Mail account. After syncing the contacts, each Outlook instance creates a birthday event for that contact, so I end up with two birthday reminders.

Is it possible to tell one of the PCs not to enter birthdays into the calendar?

Comment: I retagged as Outlook 2010 since this feature does not exist in earlier versions, just to avoid confusing the googlebots.

Comment: The feature existed in Outlook 2003!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have the same setup as me. I have an Android phone and I bought gsyncit licenses for my work and home PC's. I added the "Contacts' birthdays and events" calendar from Google and setup a gsyncit content filter to not sync events with "Birthday" in the name. Outlook still creates the Birthday events for each contact but they are not transferred to my Google calendar so the event doesn't show up there. This leaves the "Contacts' birthdays and events" calendar free to add the event. Since gsyncit isn't looking at this calendar when I synchronize the generated birthday events in Google Calendar only show up there (and on my phone). Seems to be working well for me. I see only one birthday event at each location.

Scott

Comment: Why would you pay for that service? Google already supplies this capability for you.

Comment: Google doesn't sync with Outlook.  Just to the Android device.  So if you want to sync Outlook to Android then gSyncit is one way of doing this.  Works quite well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable "My Calendars" in your mobile if you are using an Android-based phone. I normally have my Google calendar as base.